# Newton's Method

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I am trying to find out the root of an equation constraint using Newton's Method (open to any other method). The equation constraint is dependent on the roots of a quadratic equation which has one unknown term.  The equation descriptions (quadratic and constraint) are shown below. The roots of the quadratic equation are assumed to be `p1` and `p2`.

```
x^2 + x*(c1*unknown/2 + C1*c2)/(c1*c2*c3*unknown/2) + 1/(c1*c2*c3*u/2) = 0
```

with constraint

```
(1/(p2-p1))*(exp(-0.3*p2) - 1)*(c1*c2 - p2) - (exp(-0.3*p1) - 1)*(c1*c2 - p1) - 0.04 = 0
```

I am wondering if there are any other approximation methods to solve this problem if Newton's Method is not going to do so.

Matlab Code

```
p0=10*10^6;
Cc=0.65*10^-6;Rp=100*10^3;Cp=55*10^-9; z1=1/(Cp*Rp);
N = 100;error = 0.02;  
syms 'x'
a = 1;
b = ((Cc*(x/2+Rp))/(Cc*Cp*Rp*x/2));
c = 1/(Cc*Cp*Rp*x/2);
poles1 = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
poles2 = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);

p1_subterm = (exp(-0.3*poles1) - 1)*(z1 - poles1);
p2_subterm = (exp(-0.3*poles2) - 1)*(z1- poles2);
f(x) = (1/(poles2 - poles1))*p2_subterm - p2_subterm - 0.04;          
df = diff(f);  
while i <= N
 p = p0-(f(p0)/df(p0)) 
if (abs(p - p0)/abs(p)) < error 
fprintf('Solution is %f \n', double(p))
return
end
i = i + 1;
p0 = p;
end
fprintf('Solution did not converge within %d iterations \n', N)
```

Comment: I don't understand the constraint. Isn't it missing some relational operator (like `=, <=, >=`; btw. the first line isn't an equation either because it is missing `=`)? Is the constraint rather a function and you want to find the root of the function? If yes, what is the argument of the function? I see only constants. If I understand you correctly, p1 and p2 are also constant as they are defined as roots of the first function. What is the difference of *x* and *unknown* in the first line?

Comment: The equation is updated. You can click on the EquationImage link. Both the equations equate to zero. p1 and p2 are the roots of the quadratic equation. Suppose in a quadratic equation ax^2+bx+c, let's say b is unknown. The same is with my case where I say unknown in the first line. That's why p1 and p2 are expressed with unknown in my constraint. I want to find the unknown through my constraint.

Comment: Your equation is unclear.  x and unknowns; all those constants can be combined.  It's a poor visual.  What are you expecting to get out of this equation?  Values for x and the unknown where the roots are zero and the constraint is satisfied?  Newton's method for roots of a single equation is one thing; Newton-Raphson iterative solutions of equations sets is another.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: True all those constants can be combined into one. I am trying to find the unknown guy from the quadratic equation that would satisfy the constraint equation. I am open to any other method if need be.

Comment: I think I am getting what you want to do. The first line is actually a function f(x)=... The roots of this function will be p1 and p2 (f(p1)=0, f(p2)=0). Those roots will be expressions that contain the constants and an *unknown* variable. You substitute these roots into your constraint and want to find *unknown* such that the constraint is satisfied. Is this correct? Do you know how the function looks like, i.e. have you plotted it for reasonable constant values? Newton's performance heavily relies on the start point. How did you choose that? Btw, don't link to an image that contains text.

Comment: Yes there are few more methods to solve this but it depends upon values of p1 and p2 . If p1 and p2 are <0 so you cannot use Newton method for finding local maximas or roots you have to use modified newton method and if 2nd derivative does not exist so you should use Qusai newton method.   If you are not interested in any of these then you can also use Trust region method to find roots directly by making region of trust around objective function.. For your case you have to take 2nd derivative of objective function and check if roots are >0 then newton method will provide you the best results..

Comment: Please explain your question a little bit more may be i will be able to explain clearly upto what you exactly want.

Comment: You can use direct search methods like sectioning ,box search,Nelder Mead for this purpose but most famous and mostly used methods are newton direction,modified newton,Quasi newton and Trust region methods..

Comment: @ Nico- You got it correct. Constant1 is of the order 10^6, constant2 is of the order of 10^3 and constant3 is of the order 10^-6. The starting point is chosen reasonably and still it freezes after 3-4 iterations. The unknown guy can range in the order from 10^6 to 10^9.

Comment: There was a mismatched parentheses in the image, but I think I've transcribed it correctly (edit pending review)

Comment: Could you share your Newton code which freezes after 3-4 iterations? (Paste the code, not an image of it)

Comment: I have updated the code @Steve

Answer (score -1):

I don't think your code for `f(x)` corresponds to the equation listed above: In the MATLAB code `1/(poles2-poles1)` multiplies both the `exp((...)poles2)` and the `exp((...)poles1)` terms and you have `1/(c1*c2) - poles1` instead of `c1*c2 - poles1`.

I have not checked through the `poles1` and `poles2` terms as I find the 10 sets of parenthesis intimidating. It would suggest making your code more readable by breaking up each of those equations in to a number of shorter, clearer lines.

Noting that we can multiply the quadratic by `c1*c2*c3*unknown`,

```
(c1*c2*c3*unknown)*x^2 + x*2*(c1*unknown/2 + C1*c2) + 2 = 0
```

then you can write the `poles` and `f` code as

```
% Here unknown is x
syms 'x'
a = c1*c2*c3*x;
b = c1*x + 2*c1*c2;
c = 2;
poles1 = (-b + sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);
poles2 = (-b - sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c))/(2*a);

p1_subterm = (exp(-0.3*poles1) - 1)*(c1*c2 - poles1);
p2_subterm = (exp(-0.3*poles2) - 1)*(c1*c2 - poles2);
f(x) = (1/(poles2 - poles1))*p2_subterm - p2_subterm - 0.04;
```

Comment: @Steve- I have worked out my code as you pointed out but it doesn't solve the problem. It freezes after 3 iterations. The code is updated above.

Comment: @Steve- n the MATLAB code 1/(poles2-poles1) multiplies both the exp((...)poles2).---- This is what I want. The equation constraint says so as well. The idea is to find the 'unknown guy' here 'x' that would meet the constraint.

Comment: @SoumyajyotiMaji How does it freeze? What is it about the fourth iteration that causes it to hang? Can you run it for 1, 2 and 3 iterations with a profiler and see if there is a part of the code taking an exponential amount of time?